# Dimming the backlight is irreversible on a Samsung Q210 notebook, what do I do?

Tags: nvidia, display, samsung, backlight

I'm new to the community, although I have been using Ubuntu since 2010. I have a Samsung Q210 notebook;
Specs:

- Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU P8400 @ 2.26GHz × 2
- 4 Gigs RAM
- Nvidia 9200m GS (although system information in Ubuntu doesn't know)
- 194 GB HD

OS: Ubuntu 11.10
Kernel is 
3.0.0-12-generic-pae

Although Samsung seems to be infamous for problems with Ubuntu, after upgrading to Oneiric, finally the `FN` Brightness Buttons are recognized.

The only problem is, after dimming the backlight for a fixed amount of steps (3 or 4, I dare not count now because that would mean rebooting because I can't see anything), 
the display goes completely dark and using the `FN` buttons to brighten the backlight does not work anymore (before reaching that threshold, going brighter after dimming works).

Now what do I do? File a bug report? If not, what then? If yes, how? Not sure. guess I should ask here first.

Answer (score 1):

A very similar issue happened with a Toshiba I was working on. After updating Ubuntu it was solved. Just update your Ubuntu with th latest packages and you should be find. The kernel right now for 11.10 is 3.0.0-18

Answer (score 0):

You can get the monitor turned on again if you press Fn+UP several times and then Fn+F5 twice, one to turn off backlight and another one to turn it on again.

If this does nos work maybe it's because you don't have samsung-tools intalled, install it (does not resolve your problem, just enable Fn+F5).